# Help changing the order of integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

So I need to change the order of integration. I am giving the following limits, $1 \leq x \leq 9$ and $\sqrt{x} \leq y \leq 4$. I am having no luck solving this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you sketched the region?

Comment: Yah, That was the first thing I did.

Comment: So how big/small does $y$ get on the given region (this gives at least the bounds on $y$)?

Comment: The bounds I found for y would be between 1 and 4.

Comment: Right: And what is the smallest $x$ gets (should be a number)? Finally, note that $\sqrt x = y \iff y^2 = x$, which gives you the right-hand bound.

Comment: so the smallest x gets is also 1, and I originally got the limits for x to be between 1 and y^2. However I still appear to get the wrong answer.

Comment: That's almost the right region, except that the right-hand bound changes at the very top part of the region; try decomposing into the region $\{1 \le x \le y^2, 1 \le y \le 3\}$ together with a rectangle at the top.

Comment: so basically two different integrals one from (1<=x<=y^2, 1<=y<=3} then another from {1<=x<=9, 3<=y<=4}?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll give it a go -- but that sounds right!

Answer (score 2):

[image: Region D]

From the picture it is clear that if you want to change the order of integration you should integrate over the region D. Region D can be divided in two parts:

[image: Region D - splitting in two parts]

For D1 we have: integrate from $x=1$ to $x=y^2$, and $y\in(1,3)$, and for D2 we integrate from $x=1$ to $x=9$ and $y\in(3,4)$.

Calculus for D1:

$$ D_1=\int^3_1 dy \int^1_{y^2} dx $$

and for D2:

$$ D_2=\int^4_3dy\int^1_9 dx $$

Answer (score 0):

Or you could simply do the following:
$$
\text {Area} = 9\times 4 -\int_1^9 \sqrt x dx
$$